# After login to home page on go back again show login page

Tags: php, authentication, session-cookies

Hello I have problem with user when login.
When user login to profile page and on browser click on back again show login page.
How to block user who is login to see login page?

Here is code for in profile.php

```html
<?php 
include 'common.php';

session_start();
if ($_SESSION['uid_cre'] == '' && $_SESSION['login_cre'] != 'true') 
{
 $_SESSION['last_page_cre'] = 'home.php';
    header("location:home.php");
}
include 'includes/header_home.php';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an include. ie

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['????'])){
   include "login_form.php"; 
}else{
   include "logged in page here.";
}
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

1. After users are logged in successfully then you must passing username or userid of that user in $_SESSION['uid'] = $userid;
2. So on Login page, check

if(isset($_SESSION['uid']) or !empty($_SESSION['uid']))
header("location:home.php");

3. and if above 2nd condition is true then you can hide text "login" from your menu too.

Hope this solution works for your problem.